# sql server 2005 word breakers language

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I have an existing db with Full Text Search in sql server 2005. Word breakers are set in language X.

I want to change all of the word breaker languages on all of my full text indexes to language Y.

Can someone suggest a way to do this with SQL script.

What I have to do now is go to: sql server mgmt studio / my_db / storage / full text catalogs / my_catalog / properties / tables/views / and change Language for Word Breaker property one at the time.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Things changed between 2005 and 2008

Comment: title says 2005, i'll add it in the text as well. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach SQL Profiler and see what it does, then replicate it

Comment: Were you able to capture anything?